# Why is admob ad unit Frequency capping not working?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I set two impressions per minute per user but it doesn't work. Ads keep showing every time.
[IMAGE] https://i.imgsafe.org/95d5e259bf.png

on admob site they say : *A change to frequency capping, such as changing the cap from two to three, can take up to a day to take effect.*

But it has been more than **TWO** days since I applyed change to Frequency capping and it is not working ? 
Here is how I request ads :

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

I use setTestDevice so real ads wont show app because impressions on real ads can get me banned.

Comment: can someone answer ?????

Comment: Hi, is it solved? I have the same issue, capping just not works after days it has been set.

Comment: 3 years  and capping is still not working. Mine is ignoring the cap and keeps on showing ads.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in Unity plugin and reported the same. Unfortunately as of now there is a bug in the ad serving of Admob hence ad capping do not work.

> There is an open bug that's being investigated internally with frequency capping in AdMob.

[As mentioned by Google engineer](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/335#issuecomment-272055586)

Comment: In 2021, I meet the same issue for my iOS app. So this bug is still not fixing, shocking!

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following:

A change to frequency capping, such as changing the cap from two to three, can take up to a day to take effect.
A slight server delay can occasionally result in the frequency cap that you've set being exceeded.

Check it here Officially....

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6244508?ctx=tltp&hl=en